# Is it possible to run a stored procedure automatically on a new database when it is attached?

Tags: sql-server, replication, stored-procedures, automation

Replication is causing issues on our daily snapshots.

What we would like to do is remove replication automatically on a database when it is attached to the SQL server.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just run an hourly job?

Answer (score 0):

This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100669/run-stored-procedure-when-database-comes-online) may answer your question. An hourly job as pointed out by David Browne would be my choice.